# Solidity returns struct. How to decode using Python

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, python

I have a contract in Solidity with a function that returns a (nested) struct.
Using Python on the client side I can call the function using my geth node and it returns output as a hex string. How do I decode this to a string in Python? (And eventually to a dict)
How is it encoded?

When I try this: (h is the hex string)

`>>> bytes.fromhex(h[2:]).decode('utf-8')`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 313: invalid continuation byte'
```

Simplified solidity code:

```
struct StructB {
     uint256 a;
     uint256 b;
}
struct StructC {
     uint256 a;
     uint256 b;
}
struct StructA {
    uint256 a;
    uint256 b;
    StructB structB;
    StructC structC;

}

contract MyContract {
     function myFunction() external returns (StructA memory result) {
           result.a = 0;
           result.b = 1;
           result.structA.a = 0;
           result.structA.b = 1;
           result.structB.a = 0;
           result.structB.b = 1;

     }
     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode a hex string to a string using `bytes.fromhex('hexstring').decode('utf-8')`

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283984/decode-hex-string-in-python-3

https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-decode-a-hex-string-in-python

Comment: If I do that with the output string I received, I get this error: 

>>> bytes.fromhex(h).decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1

Then when I try this:

>>> bytes.fromhex(h[2:]).decode('utf-8')

I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 313: invalid continuation byte'

Comment: You need to remove the first "0x" from the string for the first ValueError.

Comment: Yes, I know. the I get the second error about position 313